# Find the newest products using Amazon API

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to find all the new Amazon products in a specific category using the Amazon Associates Web Service or any other tool ?

I tried also the RSS which give only 10 results and it is updated only once in few months. Do you have any other ideas ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once you know [the Browse Node](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=345&categoryID=12) for the category you're interested in, you can use the `BrowseNodeLookup` operation with [the `NewReleases` `ResponseGroup`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-02-01/DG/index.html?RG_NewReleases.html) to get *some* new products in that category; looks like you get 10, even in a busy category like Music » Alternative.

They don't say anything in those pages about getting more, and `NewReleases` is only a valid `ResponseGroup` for `BrowseNodeLookup` operations and not, say, `ItemSearch`, so I don't think you can get more than 10 new releases per category.

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but most products are listed under multiple browse nodes. So if you can traverse browse node hierarchy, get what you can from each and remove duplicates, you would get better coverage. Plus you can also do reverse mapping from product (its ASIN) back to all browse nodes it's assigned in, to build longer lists.